# Understand this file path (which is the server?)

Tags: server, filepath

Someone asked me what server I need rebooted.  I got this below filepath from yet-another person, and I can't understand which part of it is the server that needs rebooted...

\ustx-emcca-p1.amer.company.com\MySales_Archive\USTX-SCMAP-P1\D-Drive\

I know that we have servers that usually look like this third-level part: USTX-SCMAP-P1,but then what is this first part: \ustx-emcca-p1.amer.company.com? It doesn't seem like a Windows map which usually has a letter like (X) or (Y)

Can there be a server installed on a server??

Someone gave me a list of servers and they all start with the same two levels part (\ustx-emcca-p1.amer.company.com\MySales_Archive) but then the rest of the file path contains either USTX-SCMAP-P1, or USTX-SCMAP-P3, USTX-SCMAP-1.

Now...obviously I understand that no one here can tell me what my servers are called.  But is this naming convention common? Am I understanding how the filepath works where there can be a server on a server? How might I read this filepath? Can there be a server installed on...maybe on a virtual server??

Comment: The server name is ustx-emcca-p1.amer.company.com This is its DNS fully qualified name. The NETBIOS name would be ustx-emcca-p1.  This is a question better suited to server fault.

Comment: It is possible this is a DFS share, if that is the case, you would need to know the DFS structure.

Comment: Ohh, ok I just researched Distributed File System, and the NETBIOS protocol.  I can't say I exactly get it yet but those words are helping me understand. Then, it seems I would basically need to understand the network well enough to know exactly which server is dong what, in order to diagnose where any problem might lie...? I didn't know about that ServerFault website until now - thank you!!